# Invoking Gesture Recognizer for UIImageView inside UITableView

Tags: ios

I have a UITableView with custom cell TaskCell. TaskCell has checkboxImageView and I want that when user clicks on the checkboxImageView a method is fired. For some reason it is always firing the didSelectTableView delegate method. Here is my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"TaskCell";

    Task *task = [tasks objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    TaskCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[TaskCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];        
    }


    [cell bindTo:task];

    return cell;
}


TaskCell.m: 

-(void) prepareGestureRecognizers 
{
    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(onSingleTap:)];
    singleTapGestureRecognizer.delegate = self; 
    singleTapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1; 

    self.checkboxImageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

    [self.checkboxImageView addGestureRecognizer:singleTapGestureRecognizer];
}

-(void) onSingleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *) sender 
{
    NSLog(@"single tap!");
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

-(void) bindTo:(Task *)task
{
    [self prepareGestureRecognizers];

    self.titleLabel.text = task.title;
}
```

Comment: If I attach the gesture recognizer inside the cellForIndex then it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you add the gesture recognizer in your `TaskCell.m`, then the following line

```
singleTapGestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
```

sets the `delegate` of the recognizer to the cell, not your controller. You should add the recognizer in your controller file so that the `delegate` is properly set up.

I'm not sure if this will work as I haven't tried myself, but you can try set the recognizer up in your Storyboard and let it be a `@property` of your cell. Then you can set the delegate to be your controller in your controller file.